# django-rest-framework: Unable to handle unicode input (invalid continuation byte)

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble handling unicode characters in my input to my APIView endpoint in django-rest-framework.

I'm using the UnicodeJsonRenderer renderer class and the JSONParser class for input.

My input is as follows, using the web browsable api with a HTML form:

```
{
  "field": "hellö theré"
}
```

When I call request.DATA in my view, I get the following error message:

```
{
    "detail": "JSON parse error - 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 96: invalid continuation byte"
}
```

I debugged this pretty extensively, and I can tell that it crashes on line 60 in `parsers.py`:

```
data = stream.read().decode(encoding)
```

I'm not really sure how to resolve this issue. Though I suspect it has something to do with the encoding format, it doesn't feel right to me because I have other code in my codebase (not using the django-rest-framework library) that handles unicode input/output gracefully, as my settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET is utf-8.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I suspect it has something to do with the web browsable API sending non UTF-8 encoded character data, though the meta tag does set the charset to utf-8...

**UPDATE 2:** I've pasted below the request header of the POST request sent upon form submission with media type 'application/json'. I thought it was weird that the content-type didn't specify a charset. (I found all this using Chrome browser debug tools on the POST request being sent):

```
POST /api/stuff/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 356
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:8000/api/stuff/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: cookie-info
```

Comment: this input is in an html form, not in python

Comment: Oh. in a month after you, i've the same problem you described here https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1134

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your input is not UTF-8! The hex code `0xe2` is a continuation byte in UTF-8, which would require another hex character to be legal. *However* the hex code `0xe2` is `â` in Windows-1252. Just ensure that you properly decode the byte stream using Windows-1252 (called `cp1252` in Python):

```
text.decode('cp1252')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#unicodejsonrenderer) there is some doc about JSON renders. I suspect the problem has to do with the fact the code you have posted

```
data = stream.read().decode(encoding)
```

is trying to decode an **already decoded** string, since you are using UnicodeJsonRenderer. If you visit the link, you will realize that UnicodeJsonRenderer has no charset. So, you can't decode it.

Try using another like JsonPRenderer or HTMLFormRenderer